# Avoiding subequations from overflowing linewidth

Tags: align, labels, subequations

I am trying to have a couple of equations aligned in the subequations environment but due to the length of the first equation, it looks like the equation labels have overflowed a line above.

```
\begin{subequations}

\begin{align}
    &C_{m}\frac{dV}{dt} = I_{app} -g_{KCa}z(V-E_{K}) -g_L(V-E_L) - g_{K}n(V-E_k) - g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca})\label{ML_model_V},\\
    &\frac{dn}{dt} = \phi(n_{\infty}(V)-n)/\tau_n(V) \label{ML_model_n},\\
    &\frac{d[Ca^{2+}]}{dt} = \epsilon(-\mu g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca}) - k_{Ca}[Ca^{2+}]) \label{ML_model_Ca}.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I would like the equation labels to fit onto the same line. I have tried the {aligned} environment and scaling the equation but then the label did not appear. Unfortunately, the single letter that subequations add to the labels looks like the trigger for this behaviour in this instance (I don't really care for the extra letter but a number must be associated with each one e.g 3.1, 3.2, 3.3). Is there a solution that would show the labels and display the equations on one line?

Comment: Expand the margins. Try `\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear. This is for my thesis which has fixed margin settings to adhere to so I cannot tweak those.

Comment: Please add a minimum code from `\documentclass{...` to `\end{document}` with your complete preamble. It is very hard to read minds :)

Comment: What I see from your code, you have three equations, and I wonder why you want to align them as you do (if the three equations are connected one might think of grouping them as well, if not, then typeset them independently). Maybe you will do better if you align at the equal signs, and split some long right-hand sides. Another option is to use notation for parts of your equation, and that way get shorter right-hand sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`, and added some improvements from `diffcoeff` for the typing of derivatives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ISO] {diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}

\begin{align}
    C_{m}\diff{V}{t} & =\begin{multlined}[t] I_{app} -g_{KCa}z(V-E_{K}) -g_L(V-E_L) \\ -g_{K}n(V-E_k) - g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca})\label{ML_model_V},\end{multlined} \\
    \diff{n}{t} & = \phi(n_{\infty}(V)-n)/\tau_n(V) \label{ML_model_n},\\[1ex] 
    \diff{[Ca^{2+}]}{t} & = \epsilon(-\mu g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca}) - k_{Ca}[Ca^{2+}]) \label{ML_model_Ca}.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

\end{document}
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Split the long equation.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
C_{m}\frac{dV}{dt} = I_{app}    &-g_{KCa}z(V-E_{K}) -g_L(V-E_L) \\
                                &-g_{K}n(V-E_k) -g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca})\label{ML_model_V},\\
\end{split}\\
&\frac{dn}{dt} = \phi(n_{\infty}(V)-n)/\tau_n(V) \label{ML_model_n},\\[2ex]
&\frac{d[Ca^{2+}]}{dt} = \epsilon(-\mu g_{Ca}m_{\infty}(V)(V-E_{Ca}) -k_{Ca}[Ca^{2+}])\label{ML_model_Ca}.
\end{align}


\end{document}
```